# Jquery selector not behaving dynamically on added dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, bind

I'm trying to get a dynamic modal to display with an input field, and to retrieve the value of the input on each iteration of the modal's addition to the DOM. Currently, the input is assigned the correct value on the first iteration, and retains that value for each subsequent iteration.

For instance, when I enter '3' in to the input on the first time the modal is called, the behavior is as expected. However, the second or any subsequent time the modal is created, and I enter a different value such as '4' or '5', I am always receiving '3' as the value of the input.

Here is what the code looks like to create the modal:

```
//show item choice input screen when item clicked
$(".item_choice").click(function() {
    selectedItemId = $(this).attr('id');
    var overlay = "<div class=\"grey_out\">\
    <div class=\"choice_details\">\
        <h2>"+selectedItemId+"</h2>\
        <div class=\"spacing_vert_small\"></div>\
        <h3>Quantity</h3>\
        <input class=\"choice_quantity\" type=\"text\"/>\
        <a class=\"choice_quantity_submit\" >OK</a>\
    </div>\
        </div>";

    $(".page_header").before(overlay);
});
```

And here is what it looks like to retrieve the value of the field from the modal:

```
$( document ).on( "click", "a.choice_quantity_submit", function() {

    var quantityItem = $(".choice_quantity").val();
    var domId = '#' + selectedItemId + ' h2';
    $(domId).text(quantityItem);

    $(".grey_out").fadeOut('slow', function() {
        console.log('completed?');
    });
});
```

I think the issue is that the `document.on('click')` is called once, and references the original iteration that the overlay is created. Any help to make the JQuery selector of the overlay behave dynamically would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
var quantityItem = $(".choice_quantity").val();
```

is getting the value of the first element with class name ="choice_quantity".  You need to change it to

```
var quantityItem = $(this).prev('input').val();
```